# Matlab: How to calculate integration with a upper limit variable?

Tags: matlab

For example, I want to calculate this
[image]

This is a function, which means, in the `[0..t0]`, there is a corresponding value for `y(t)`.

In this specifc example, `p(t)` is given by a set of data, not a expression. `m` and `w` are all given constant.

My code is:

```
  t = 0:dt:t0; % t0 is the end point
  dy = p.*sin(w*(???));
  y = trapz(t, dy)/(m*w);
```

I don't know what to put inside the (???)

UPDATE:
Please notice that there is a `t`, the upper limit, inside the integration

Comment: Define a vector `tau = [0:dtau:t]` such that your `p(tau)` values are all available. Then simply put `dy = p(tau) .* sin( w * (t - tau));`

Comment: But `trapz` returns only 1 result, right? What I want is a set of results correpsonding `t`. @JandeGier

Answer (score 0):

use cumtrapz instead of trapz. Return value is a vector with the cumulated integral between 0 and t for each t

Comment: But the `t` inside the integration also changes. How can I deal with it?